# Division and == in python, why gives different answers

Tags: python

Why in the code below

```
n, m= 5.0, 10
print(m/n==2, m/n is 2)
```

returns `True` and `False` if `m/n` returns `2.0`, then why first part is True

Comment: This will return a float, 2.0. And not 2

Comment: As the suggested dupe explain, `is` compares actual memory locations. A float and integer are different types, so they won't ever point to the same object in memory. However, python will allow you to compare equality between floats and ints. So it tells you that indeed, 2.0 and 2 are equal.